# Bcrypt, what is meant salt and cost?

Tags: encryption, zend-framework2, bcrypt

I was always using MD5 for encrypting passwords, but I read that it's should no more be used, and instead use bcrypt..

I'm using zendframework 2 , where I found it describing bcrypt configurations as follows:

```
$bcrypt = new Bcrypt(array(
    'salt' => 'random value',
    'cost' => 11
));
```

what is the salt and what is the cost ? and how could them be used?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A salt is random text added to the string to be hashed. For example, you don't hash `my_secret_password`; you hash something like `1jfSLKe$*@SL$#)(Sslkfs$34:my_secret_password`.  The reason for this is that it makes it hard to set up a "rainbow table" to brute-force the passwords, even if the entire database of hashed passwords is stolen. If every password has a different salt, only the very weakest passwords (like "password" or "123456", which you should prohibit anyway) will be guessed.

A cost is a measure of how many times to run the hash -- how slow it is. You want it to be slow. Again, this is a redundant layer of security for if the hashed passwords are stolen. It makes it prohibitively expensive to brute-force anything.

You can read a good description here: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/51983/35405

Comment: So, when a user register in my site, Bcrypt will add a random text to his password,
when he try login again, how could I verify the login-password matches the register one ( I don't know the random salt )

Comment: As explained [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.crypt.password.html), you would use `$bcrypt->verify($password, $storedPassword)`, where `$password` is what the user just entered and `$storedPassword` is the saved (salted and hashed) value. The salt is stored in the return value when you create the hash, so you don't have to store it separately.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get what you mean by : "The salt is stored in the return value when you create the hash",
The return value of creating the hash when the user register is not stored ... So when verifying the user , how could I know the salt? or you mean that I should store the salt which is in the return value?

Comment: You *must* store the hash that you create; otherwise, you cannot verify the user's credentials. The hashed password will be something like `$P$BRQWcDaMVzgWrFUtP/ptynlewMDR5.1`. The `BRQWcDaMVzgWrFUtP` is the salt. Store the whole thing (`$P$BRQWcDaMVzgWrFUtP/ptynlewMDR5.1`) without breaking it apart. Without the entire string, you can't check the user's credentials.

Comment: @darroosh, suppose you and another user have the same password. Without a salt, they'll have the same hashed password. So you can guess the other user's password. This is the essence of the "rainbow table" attack. A rainbow table is a pre-hashed (very large) list of the most common passwords (or sometimes all passwords less than a given length)

Comment: TL;DR: the server must generate the salt when password is changed. All other use requires using the stored password starting with `$` to be used which contains the original salt used when the password was changed in addition to the actual hash value.